# how to export ipa file from visual studio 2017 cross platform application (xamarin)

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.ios, xamarin.forms, visual-studio-2017

I built a cross platform application (xamarin)  in visual studio 2017. 
I want export a IPA file for install application in IPhone without using appstore.

According to the searches I have done, these steps are done:

1. I connected a iPhone to the MacOs.
2. I added apple id to the xcode that was previously used on the iPhone.
3. I created a ios application project in xcode with bundle Identifier that inserted in visual studio ios project and also provisioning profile was created.
4. I selected release mode on iPhone (my iPhone name shows).
5. in ios bundle signin tab from properties of ios project  i selected iPhone developer on signin identity and  also i selected ios team provisioning profile on provisioning profile.
6. in ios ipa options tab from properties of ios project i checked build iTunes package archive and set package name.
7. I deployed ios project and application installed on iPhone successfully and ipa file was credited in bin\iPhone\release.

finally, here's my problem:

I copy ipa file in MacOs and i open iTunes and i drag ipa file into apps tab.
application added in apps with name and icon correctly.
after that i connect iPhone to the MacOs and then i go to iPhone apps and click on install button of my application and then click on sync button.

application installed in IPhone but the application icon was black and application will not run and display unable to install application error.

Comment: Which type of provisioning profile did you use ? Is it for  Enterprise?

Comment: No, I have a free provisioning profile (IOS Team Provisioning Profile Or XCode Managed Profile)